# Kohana Route, не работает маршрут

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

На сайте нужно прописать route для страницы news.html, прописываю как надо, но он не работает (404), список роутов:

```
Route::set('news', '<news>', array('news' => '(news.html)')) // Не работает
    ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action'     => 'news',
));
// Лишние роуты опустил

Route::set('default', '(<stuff>)', array('stuff' => '(.*)'))
    ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Если я убираю route `news`, то срабатывает, естественно, последний.
Но всё же с ним выдает 404, а значит роут цепляется. Но почему Kohana не может его отобразить?

С контроллером тоже всё в порядке, есть `Controller_Index` с методом `public function action_news()`

Где я допускаю ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::set('news', '(<controller>(<action>))<stuff>', array('stuff' => '(news.html)'))
    ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action'     => 'news',
));
```

Так заработало